# How to properly extend Model in Magento 2?

Tags: model, magento2.1.5

Can someone show me how to properly extend this core Magento 2 model?

> ```
> vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to rewrite (in the Magento sense) classes that are used as superclasses, including abstract classes (by definition).
So, you can't rewrite an abstract class. The rewrite system works because Magento uses a factory pattern to instantiate model, blocks, and helpers.
Since an abstract class is never instantiated, it can never be rewritten.
Solution for you problem is you should rewrite the derive class that extends this abstract class.